# Integrating factor for heat differential

Tags: thermodynamics, first-law-of-thermodynamics

I want to calculate the integration factor $\mu(E,V)$ for the differential $\mathrm{d}\sigma = \mu(E,V) \delta Q = \mu(E,V) \mathrm{d}E + \mu(E,V)p(u) \mathrm{d}V$.  $p$ is a function of $u$ with $u = \frac{E}{V}$.

For a general $p$ I did the following

$\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial\mu}{\partial V} &= \frac{\partial (\mu \cdot p)}{\partial E} \\
&= p \cdot \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial E} + \mu \cdot \frac{\partial p}{\partial E} \\
&= p \cdot \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial E} + \mu \cdot \frac{\partial p}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial E} \\
&= p \cdot \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial E} + \frac{\mu}{V} \cdot\frac{\partial p}{\partial u}
\end{align}$

Can I solve this even further for a general $p$?

Now, I tried calculating $\mu$ for a specific $p = c \cdot u$. When I inserted this into the above equation I get

$\begin{align} 
\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial V} &= c \cdot \frac{E}{V} \cdot \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial E} + \frac{\mu}{V} \cdot c = \frac{c}{V} \left( E \cdot \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial E} + \mu \right)
\end{align}$

How do I go on from here for getting $\mu$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write equation $\begin{align} 
\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial V} &= c \cdot \frac{E}{V} \cdot \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial E} + \frac{\mu}{V} \cdot c = \frac{c}{V} \left( E \cdot \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial E} + \mu \right)
\end{align}$ as 
$\begin{align} 
\frac{V}{\mu} \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial V} &=  {c} \left(1+ \frac{E}{\mu} \cdot \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial E} \right)
\end{align}$ and introduce new variables 
$\begin{align} \textrm{ln}E = \epsilon, \textrm{ln}V = \nu, 
\textrm{ln}\mu(E,V) = M(\epsilon, \nu) \end{align}$ and upon substitution you get
$$\begin{align} 
\frac{\partial M}{\partial \nu} &=  {c} \left(1+ \frac{\partial M}{\partial \epsilon} \right)
\end{align}$$
A trial solution to this is $M(\epsilon, \nu) = f(\epsilon) + g(\nu)$, substituting you get $$g'(\nu) = c(1+f'(\epsilon)) = K,$$ where $K$ is independent of $\epsilon, \nu$ hence we can integrate:
$g'(\nu) = \nu_0 +K\nu$ and $f(\epsilon)=\epsilon_0 + \epsilon(K/c-1)$. Now going back to the original variables the integrating factor will be $$\mu(E,V) = \textrm{exp}[M(\epsilon, \nu)]\\
=\textrm{exp}[f(\epsilon)+g(\nu)]\\
=\textrm{exp}[\epsilon_0 + \epsilon(K/c-1)]\textrm{exp}[\nu_0 +K\nu]
=E_0\textrm{exp}[\textrm{ln} E (K/c-1)]V_0\textrm{exp}[K\textrm{ln}V]
=V_0E_0E^{(K/c-1)}V^K 
$$

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be $g(\nu) = c(1+f'(\epsilon)) =K$ and at the last line $V_0 E_0 E e^{K/c-1} V e^{K}$?

Comment: $\textrm{exp}[K\textrm{lnV}]= \textrm{exp}[\textrm{ln}(V^K)]=V^K$, the other is similar

Comment: You also also asked if you could solve/simplify your 1st equation $\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial V} = p \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial E} + \frac{\mu}{V} \frac{\partial p}{\partial u}$ for $p$ in general. I think not, because you have two unknowns $\mu(E,V)$ and $p(u)$ and one equation. Since this is an *ordinary* 1st order linear differential equation in the unknown $p$ with variable $u$ I expect that the most you can do is to solve it as function of $\mu$ with arbitrary parameters $E,V$.